# Attribute error when using signal.pthread_sigmask

Tags: python

I keep getting an error every time I try to use signal.pthread_sigmask

The error is:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pthread_sigmask'

```
def clean_up():
        socket.close()
        context.term()

def receive_signal(signal, stack):
        signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, signal.SIGINT)
        print ("Exiting because I received a signal:", signum)
        clean_up()
        sys.exit(1)

#Create zmq context and bind socket
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

#Register signal handler with signals
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, receive_signal)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Skipped some import lines? ;-) If the `signal` argument received by `receive_signal` is an integer,you will have no luck invoking any module function `signal.pthread_sigmask` (also not known to me). Right? Usually the handlers have an argument named `signum` or the like to memorize that better. More details and valid code (from isolation perspective) needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By naming the parameter in your `receive_signal` function `signal` you are shadowing the module `signal`, just call it something else, you seem to be using something called `signum` maybe that is what you ment to use instead?

```
def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    ...
```

Comment: Yes I just realized that on my own.  Not sure how that happened.  Thx anyway.